# Which option{PCI | PC-E | Onboard} would be suitable? Also installing my Graphic card driver hangs the PC

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, bios

[MY PC INFO](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00683778&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=3198158)

[MY MOTHERBOARD INFO](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00714533&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=3198158)

I have an onboard ATI X200 Graphic card.
The problem is that my BIOS shows 3 options for Primary Video Adapter:

1>PCI

2>PC-E

3>Onboard

Q1>Which option would be suitable for my onboard Graphic card?
Currently my BIOS has PCI as the option selected and still my Graphic card works fine.

Q2>Whenever i try to intall driver for my Graphic card or an update for my Graphic card, it just hangs.Why is it happening?

Comment: Shopping questions are offtopic, also, ask only one question at a time

Answer (score 2):

A1:  This setting specifies which graphics adapter is initialised first if there is more than one installed in your system.  You have only onboard graphics installed, therefore this setting is irrelevant to you currently.  However, it would be appropriate to set this to PCIe in case you decide to install an additional PCI Express graphics adapter in the future, this setting will ensure that the new card would be correctly initialised without further configuration changes.

A2:  Are you certain you are installing the correct driver for the correct operating system?  Also, are you sure you do not already have the most up-to-date driver installed?  What do you mean when you say 'it just hangs', what hangs - the installer, windows?  Download the driver fresh and try again.

Comment: Hey,Thanx
Q2:after extracting itself[the executable driver file],it just hang the windows...